# как сохранить вывод os.system

Tags: python

как мне сохранить в переменную то что вывела консоль при работе модуля oc
например: `os.system("ipconfig")`

Comment: Использовать [subproccess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) вместо `os`.

Comment: а конкретнее, пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

***Пример:***

```py
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig', universal_newlines=True)
```